# Circle to Circle collision function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision

I wrote a circle to circle collision function but I think I made a little mistake and I can't see to find it.

```js
function testCollisionArc(arc1,arc2){
  return arc1.x + arc1.r + arc2.r > arc2.x 
  && arc1.x < arc2.x + arc1.r + arc2.r
  && arc1.y + arc1.r + arc2.r > arc2.y 
  && arc1.y < arc2.y + arc1.r + arc2.r
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are seeing? And can you add an example that is producing this result?

Comment: Please explain where do you have this mistake, or what's happening wrong

Comment: it ought to be relatively obvious to anyone capable of answering this question that the code in question looks more like a box intersection test than a circle test

Answer (score 1):

A circle hasnt edges and borders ( :0 ).
You need to get the distance between both:

```
var distance=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(arc1.x-arc2.x,2)+Math.pow(arc1.y-arc2.y,2));//the 'sentence of Pythagoras' as we say in German
return arc1.r+arc2.r>distance;
```

Comment: `^ 2` isn't correct javascript (it's legal, but not correct in this context)

Comment: You can use `**` to raise to the power but only on modern browsers. (Chrome, Firefox) or use babel. Thus 2 to the power 4 is `2**4` and cube root of 2 is `2**(1/3)`. Also there is the math function `Math.hypot(x,y)` returns the hypotenuse and supports multi dimensions `Math.hypot(x, y, z, w)` returns length of 4D vector `{x,y,z,w}`